# Failed to open a port in my ubuntu machine

Tags: firewall

Recently I added to iptables a rule which was supposed to allow incoming traffic through port 993. The rule I used is the one shown below:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
```

After I entered the rule, I ran "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4" and rebooted the server. However when I use the telnet command to check the port I am getting following error.

telnet localhost 993

it tells me the connection is refused by the host (my server). This is not only happening to this port but to other ports I try to open. Am I doing something wrong, running a wrong command, etc? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-A` appends the rule to the end of the list of rules. So if a previous rule drops the packet, the packet is not going to be accepted. Use `-I` instead of `-A`. Also, check if a rule in other tables or in chain PREROUTING drops the packet.